# Posting fields under hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a wizard-like bootstrap 3 form that has two steps like this:

```html
<form id="sign-up" class="form-horizontal">
  <div id="step1">
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Goal</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select name="inputGoal" id="inputGoal" class="form-control">
            <option value="1" data-val="Lose some weight">Lose Weight</option>
            <option value="2" data-val="Gain some weight">Gain Weight</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputDob" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Date of Birth</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="inputDob" id="inputDob" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputGender" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="inputGender1" value="Female" name="inputGender"><i class="fa fa-venus"></i> Female
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="inputGender2" value="Male" name="inputGender"><i class="fa fa-mars"></i> Male
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputUnit" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Units</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="inputUnit" id="inputUnit1" value="metric" checked="checked"> Metric (kg,cm)
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="inputUnit" id="inputUnit2" value="imperial"> Imperial (lbs,ft,in)
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="metric">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputHeight" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Height(cm)</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputHeight" placeholder="Height in cm" name="inputHeight">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputWeight" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Weight(Kg)</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputWeight" placeholder="Weight in Kg" name="inputWeight">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="imperial">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputHeightFt" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Height(ft,in)</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputHeightFt" placeholder="ft" name="inputHeightFt">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputHeightIn" placeholder="in" name="inputHeightIn">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputWeightLbs" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Weight(lbs)</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputWeightLbs" placeholder="Weight in Lbs" name="inputWeightLbs">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button id="calorie">Calculate BMR <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div id="step2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputBMR" class="col-sm-4 control-label">BMR</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBMR" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputFullname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFullname" placeholder="Full Name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Programme</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="inputProgramme" id="inputProgramme1" value="1" checked="">
              4 WEEK SILVER PLAN
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="inputProgramme" id="inputProgramme2" value="2">
              12 WEEK GOLD PLAN
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
            <input type="radio" name="inputProgramme" id="inputProgramme3" value="3">
              12 WEEK PLATINUM PLAN
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputMobile" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Mobile</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputMobile" placeholder="Mobile">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button id="modal-back" class="pull-left">Back</button>
      <button class="pull-right" id="btnRegister">Let's GO!</button>                                
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Step 2 is hidden at when the page loads through css `display:none` and only displayed when you click on the "Calculate BMR" button which hides step 1 via jquery like this:

```js
$('#step1').hide();
$('#step2').show();
```

The challenge I am having is that when I submit the form, none of the `step2` fields are posted. It might help to know that the form is loaded in a modal.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not the answer, but not all of your inputs have names. You need names to view the posted data. Also, post your submit button code.

Comment: How do you submit your form? jQuery? can you post the code?

Comment: I just noticed, thanks a lot! It's almost 3am you can imagine fatigue! Thanks for your time, an extra pair of eyes always helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would try using jQuery to query for the fields when you make your post request and build a data object manually and then fire it off with a

Query input fields and set data object by:

```
var data = {}
data.email = $('#inputEmail').val()
//query for other inputs and set them as keys of this data object
```

Then send the post request with the specified data that you queried for:

```
$.post('url/where/data/goes', data).then(function(response){
  console.log('successful post request',response)
  // Do something with response
}, function(err){
  console.log("submit unsuccessful", err)
})
```

Also, if you name your inputs they should all be put into an object when you submit your data to the specified backend.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to try get me out of the run I was stuck in. @Graham T actually got it, I missed name attribute on some inputs hence the issue. Thanks again for coming out and quite timely